# How to distinguish winphone from UWP in xamarin PCL

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library, xamarin.uwp, xamarin.winphone, cross-device

I have a xamarin native project.

In the PCL I would like to differentiate if its running winphone or uwp

I can easily differentiate iOS,Android and windows as whole(winphone and UWP)

I don't know how to differentiate winphone from UWP

Here is what I tried

```
 var platform = CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Platform;
            if (platform != Plugin.DeviceInfo.Abstractions.Platform.Windows && platform != Plugin.DeviceInfo.Abstractions.Platform.WindowsPhone){

 }
```

even uwp project says its windowsphone ..

I was hoping xamarin.winphone is windowsphone and uwp is windows.. but turns out both are winphone

I am using CrossDeviceInfo .. I couldn't find a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

use [Device.RuntimePlatform](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Device.RuntimePlatform/)

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.WinPhone) ...
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Windows) ...
```

Comment: its for xamarin.forms.. I am using xamarin Native